# Is the Play! Framework a good choice to make apps for a VPS in Digitalocean?

Tags: jakarta-ee, playframework, playframework-2.0, digital-ocean

I have a VPS on digitalocean.com and want to make a personal website 
with the java Play! Framework. The service include 512 memory and 20 GB SSD, among other features.

I installed an Ubuntu 12.04 64 bits image.

I have not previous experience with Play!, but as far as I can
judge by the tutorials on internet, it seems a powerful tool for
fast application development . Anyway, I have not to much time
to spend and I would like to prevent any further problem of compatibility with
my server environment.

Do you think that, given the resources of my VPS, it would be 
reliable to use Play?.

What I want to avoid is the scenario where, because something regarding the framework, I run out of resources pretty fast after my site is released.

There is a tutorial about how to deploy Play! apps in digitalocean with a Dokku Image, but I need to use the Ubuntu Image I already have.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes : resources are equivalent to the free plan of Heroku, which handles very well any basic Play! Framework project.

If you want to make your personal website, Play! Framework is a hammer to push a pin. You could use just HTML/Css from a template.

If you are thinking to make your website more complex than few html pages : like have a database, Play! Framework is a good thing (look about node.js too).

About resources : your digitalOcean server handles 1 request at once, so if your site takes 200ms to handle a request, it will handle 5 requests in a second. (warning : downloading a stylesheet or a JS file is a request)

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to deploy one of Play samples in your VPS.
Then, check your ressources!

Comment: I deployed the Hello World example and everything looks OK, but what will happen when the app grows? I don't want to start coding with another framework from the scratch :s

Comment: it depends on how big your application will be. Sample applications are light (few routes, few classes and few templates). So if your application is similar, it will be the same. But, if your application will be big (hundred of routes, classes or templates), yes, more ressources will be used.

Comment: I think it depends rather of the number of requests you're gonna handle per second, and how fast you are to handle a request :

On your free plan, 1 request a time so if 200ms per request, you can handle 5 requests per second.

Answer (score 1):

Java consume high resource, Play! is using Java so it also consume resource. Let me share experience on my DigitalOcean 512MB RAM plan to host Play!.

With Ubutu Server 14.04, the system used around 90MB RAM when I am using PHP + MySQL. However, a single Play! process could take ~200MB - 280MB RAM. By default, DigitalOcean does not enable SWAP partition. Your Play! may even cannot be started, or may get killed very soon, with not enough memory error.  Enable your server's SWAP partition is easy , and even no need to restart. But  your server will significantly drop

For Play! 2.3+ it used Activator and Play! will not start on 512MB ram server.